# Numbers are always in the right side

Tags: adobe-indesign

Why is the number always appear on the right side? I already set the language to English: USA and the font to Arial, not Arabic.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The ***alignment*** must also be set to the ***Left margin***. That's the first setting to check.

Format > Text > Align > Left

If the alignment is correct, you must also specify that the ***writing direction*** is ***left to right*** or ***LTR*** to get the writing to start on the left margin for some text layout software.

Format > Text > Paragraph - Writing Direction > Left to Right